# "Dll load failed" error when trying to install Animation Nodes in 2.81b and 2.8

Tags: animation-nodes

Not a top notch programmer here, just an artist.  Recently tried using AN with 2.8 and 2.81b but have been getting this error (Image Attached).  Too much to type and I'm not sure exactly what's wrong.

What's the fix for this?  Did I just install this wrong or is it something deeper?

It does work with 2.79 so I'm a bit confused.   Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to install [vc_redist.x64.exe](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads#section-2) which is a package for Microsoft Visual Studio that Animation Nodes requires to work.  Once you have installed this, you will need to restart your computer and then attempt to enable the add-on again.